# How can I display the table depending on a selected item in the list?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this list:

```
<?php if (!$this->ion_auth->in_group(array('Patient'))) { ?>
<li class="">
 <div>
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1"><?php echo lang('categorie'); ?></label>
    <select id="tableSelector" onchange="showTable()" class="form-control">
       <option value="select">SELECT</option>
       <option value="femmeEnceinte">Femme enceinte</option>
       <option value="personnels">Personnel</option>
       <option value="autres">Autres</option>
     </select> 
 </div>       
</li>
<?php } ?>
```

And I want if we select the first element of the list, that the first table is displayed, if we select the second element, the second table is displayed and the same thing for the third.

These are the three tables:

```
<?php if (!$this->ion_auth->in_group(array('Patient'))) { ?>
   <div id="femmeEnceinte" class="tab-pane"> <div class="">

<!--First  table (femmeEnceinte) start-->

<div class="adv-table editable-table " id="femmeEnceint" style="display: none">
<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered" id="table_femmeE">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th><?php echo lang('patient_id'); ?></th>                        
         <th><?php echo lang('name'); ?></th>
         <th><?php echo lang('cas'); ?></th>
         <th><?php echo lang('birth_date'); ?></th>
         <th><?php echo lang('address'); ?></th>
 <?php if ($this->ion_auth->in_group(array('Doctor', 'admin', 'Receptionist'))) { ?>
         <th><?php echo lang('department'); ?></th>
         <th><?php echo lang('sex'); ?></th>
 <?php } ?>
    </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
     <style>
        .img_url{
            height:20px;
            width:20px;
            background-size: contain; 
            max-height:20px;
            border-radius: 100px;
         }
     </style>
<?php foreach ($patients as $patient) { ?>
   <tr class="">
      <td><?php echo $patient->id; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $patient->name; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $patient->phone; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $patient->birthdate; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $patient->address; ?></td>
<?php if ($this->ion_auth->in_group(array('Doctor', 'admin', 'Receptionist'))) { ?>
      <td><?php echo "Département"; // echo " "; $patient->department                             ?></td>
      <td> <?php echo $patient->sex; ?></td>
  <?php } ?>
 </tr>
 <?php } ?>
 </tbody>
</table>
</div>
       <!--first table (femmeEnceinte) end-->

       <!--second table (personnel) start-->
<div class="adv-table editable-table " style="display: none" id="personnel">
     <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered" id="editable-sample">
     <thead>
          <tr>
            <th><?php echo lang('patient_id'); ?></th>                        
            <th><?php echo lang('name'); ?></th>
            <th><?php echo lang('phone'); ?></th>
<?php if ($this->ion_auth->in_group(array('admin', 'Accountant', 'Receptionist'))) { ?>
            <th><?php echo lang('sex'); ?></th>
<?php } ?>
            <th class="no-print"><?php echo lang('options'); ?></th>
          </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
           <style>
              .img_url{
                 height:20px;
                 width:20px;
                 background-size: contain; 
                 max-height:20px;
                 border-radius: 100px;
              }
           </style>
       </tbody>
    </table>
 </div>
    <!--Second table (personnel) end-->

    <!--Third table (autres) start-->
<div class="adv-table editable-table " id="divautres" id="autre">
   <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered" id="table_autres">
     <thead>
       <tr>
         <th><?php echo lang('patient_id'); ?></th>                        
         <th><?php echo lang('name'); ?></th>
         <th><?php echo lang('cas'); ?></th>
         <th><?php echo lang('birth_date'); ?></th>
         <th><?php echo lang('address'); ?></th>
         <th><?php echo lang('sex'); ?></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
       <style>
         .img_url{
            height:20px;
            width:20px;
            background-size: contain; 
            max-height:20px;
            border-radius: 100px;
          }
       </style>
         <?php foreach ($patients as $patient) { ?>
            <tr class="">
              <td><?php echo $patient->id; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $patient->name; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $patient->phone; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $patient->birthdate; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $patient->address; ?></td>
              <td> <?php echo $patient->sex; ?></td>
            </tr>
         <?php } ?>
      </tbody>
     </table>
</div>
<!--Third table (autre) end-->

 </div>
 </div>
<?php } ?>
```

This is the code for showing and hiding tables. I want this code just to limit just to these three tables. Because the page has other tables which are not concerning by the SELECT options. Then they can't be hidden and shown

```
 function showTable() {
 // Hide all tables
  var tables = document.getElementsByClassName("adv-table");
      for (var i = 0; i < tables.length; i++) {                                                   
        tables[i].style.display = "none";
      }
// Show the selected table
var selectedTableId = document.getElementById("tableSelector").value;                                                             document.getElementById(selectedTableId).style.display = "block";
     }
```

I am advised to use JavaScript even though I actually know nothing about it.

Comment: Why have you formatted the code in your question so that readers need to excessively horizontally scroll to read it?

Comment: @mickmackusa There is a limited number of characters to put on the forum space. I wanted to put everything for greater transparency but when validating, I received the message that it would take 30,000 characters if I'm not mistaken. And I was forced to remove others who were not affected by this problem.

Comment: ...but there are excess whitespace characters. I am recommending the you remove needless whitespaces so that readers can actually read your code without scrolling horizontally.

Comment: Where is the code for your `showTable()` function?

Comment: @SamuelAsor  let me add it

Answer (score 0):

You are very close. You can try the code below:

```js
function showTable() {
    // Hide all tables
    var tables = document.getElementsByClassName("adv-table");
    for (var i = 0; i < tables.length; i++) {
        tables[i].style.display = "none";
    }

    // Show the selected table
    var selectedTableId = document.getElementById("tableSelector").value;
    document.getElementById(selectedTableId).style.display = "block";
}
```

I haven't tested it, but it should work.

Comment: This is the same code I had. By the way this first Javascript instruction which consists of hiding the tables hides all the tables which are on the page or what I want is that only the tables relating to the SELECT options are hidden except the others but this is not not the case with this code